# find a specific number in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, lazy-evaluation

I have this variable x, that contains this string:
`var x="Math.pow(5,3)";`
How can I find the exponent(in this case 3), considering that my "Math.pow" string may contain any number as its base and exponent.

I was thinking to combine somehow the RegEx with the`Number()` function, but no result came up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `regex` and search for the digits between `,` and `)`:

```js
var x = "Math.pow(5,3)";
var reg = /,(\d+)\)/;

console.log(x.match(reg)[1]);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Or a bit shorter, just search for digits after `,`:

```js
var x = "Math.pow(5,34)";
var reg = /,(\d+)/;

console.log(x.match(reg)[1]);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: hey @eisbehr , this will not work for something like `x = "Math.pow(51,23)";` But its hard from this question to gues if it even should work. Gj and thumb up

Comment: Sorry, now it does @Andurit

Comment: this is how a stupid question like mine gets more than a good answer